# NSImageView not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsimageview

I am trying put an image in a view. This is my code:

```
NSImageView *imView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 480, 360)];
    NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:@"image.png"];
    [imView setImage:myImage];
    [theView addSubview:imView];
    [window setContentView:theView];
```

But the window is blank(image doesn't get drawn). If I place a textfield in the view for example.. it works perfectly, but not NSImageView...I checked the console and there's no warning/error messages...
Thanks!

Comment: Check whether `myImage` is valid: `NSLog(@"image is valid? %@", [imView isValid] ? @"yes" : @"no");`

Comment: Also, you’re leaking both `imView` and `myImage` in this code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You're right, its not valid. What could be wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, i know about the leaks, I am merely trying to learn how to put image in an nsview i can careless about the memory right now its a dummy project i created just to test...thanks though.

Comment: Most likely Cocoa is not finding that file. Try using `+imageNamed:` instead. Where is that file located?

Comment: Inside my project folder, in xcode i can see it in my Resources folder.

Comment: Oh, +imageNamed: worked! Thanks man! Still would like to know what was wrong with initbyReferencingFile..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `[imView isValid]` returns false, this means that `NSImage` hasn’t been able to create an image based on that file. A common reason is that the file couldn’t been located. From the documentation of `-initByReferencingFile:`,

> *filename*
>   A full or relative path name specifying the file with the desired image data. Relative paths must be relative to the current working directory.

This means that the behaviour of `-initByReferencingFile:` depends on the current directory, and ideally you should pass the full path name.

A better solution is to use `+imageNamed:` instead because of two reasons: it uses an image cache and it is able to look for a file inside the application bundle.